# Is it possible to load a TensorFlow 2.0 model in Java?

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Wasn't able to find the answer on Google and the questions asked here all seem close but not the same. Sorry if I overlooked something.

Is it currently already possible to load a model written in Python TensorFlow 2.0.0-beta1 in Java 8? The model would use the Keras Sequential API. If this is possible, I appreciate a pointer to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: If the model is saved in the .h5 format, then using `tf.lite.TfLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file()` you can convert the model to a .tflite file which we can run on Android.

Comment: TFLite only works for Android. My question is about Java 8.

Comment: Is it possible for you to convert the model to a .pb file whose input and output node names are known to you?

Comment: If you save the graph in .pb yes. However, they just officially released TF 2.0 but they haven't released it on Maven. Once they do that, the process of using a graph would be more or less the same.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I saw that and can't wait for the Maven release!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this if you first convert the model to a tflite file as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_tfkeras_file_):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("keras_model.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Which you can then load and run as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_java):

```java
public Interpreter(@NotNull File modelFile);

try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(file_of_a_tensorflowlite_model)) {
  interpreter.run(input, output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately TFLite only works for Android, my question is about Java 8.